# goo.gl: no URL history

Tags: url-shortening, goo.gl

I've shortened and shared several URLs with goo.gl during the last few days. I'm logged in and have tested the URLs to work, but the URL history seems to remain empty, only showing:

> No entries found. Start building your goo.gl short URL history now!

What's going on?

Comment: Maybe you weren't logged in when you were creating the link.. Try to add one more now to see if it stays in the history :)

Comment: I have definitely been logged in all the time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was causing the problem.
The bookmarklet that I used didn't allow the URL to be added to my account history.

```
javascript:document.location='http://savanttools.com/get2post.asp?x-form-action=http://goo.gl/action/shorten&url='+encodeURIComponent(document.location.href)
```

Going back to doing it manually for now.

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to browser cache. Try clearing your browser cache.

Also, I'm not sure what type of Google account you have (Apps or non Apps), but Apps accounts have more limitation in the Googleverse. If you're using a google apps account, try using a personal account/gmail

Comment: The problem persists, across several computers and different browsers. I'm using a regular non-apps account.